# How to use async/await in for by Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to know how to use async/await in for by Swift.

```
var data = [String]()
    func uploadImage(images: [UIImage]) async -> Array<String> {
        
        for image in images{
            
                 ImageUploader.uploadImages(image: image, type: .post) { imageUrl async in
                    await self.data.append(imageUrl)
                }
            
        }
        return data
    }
```

```
static func uploadImages(image: UIImage,type: UploadType,completion: @escaping(String) -> Void) async{
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else{return}
        let ref = type.filePath
        
        ref.putData(imageData,metadata: nil){ _, error in
            if let error = error{
                print("DEBUG: Failed to upload image\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            print("Successfully uploaded image")
            
            ref.downloadURL{ url, _ in
                guard let imageUrl = url?.absoluteString else {return}
                completion(imageUrl)
            }
        }
    }
```

When I call the func uploadImage, not waiting for `self.data.append(imageUrl)` The data return empty array.

I want for `uploadImage` to wait `append`,then the string array should return array including uploadImages'imageUrl.

How should I correct this. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot `return data` like this unless the function is async

Comment: Decorating a function with “async” does not make a function compatible with “async await” you have to use continuation to convert and completion handler to async await. Watch Meet async await

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread 1: EXC\_BAD\_INSTRUCTION when fetching data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636543/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-when-fetching-data)

Comment: @jnpdx I edited this above code. I added `async` in uploadImage function and callback function in `for`. In the callback function I got `Cannot pass function of type '(String) async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type`. I wrote `Task`, but not resolve. Please advice more.

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you, What do you mean? Did you mean by `uploadImages` function? To use async not using  completion handler, should I use async await for  the`uploadImages function`?

Comment: Yes upload images need a continuation, that version is not an async await compatible function. The goal is to remove the completion handler and “continue” when then uploading is done.

Comment: @loremipsum What do you mean by `continuation`? Is it `completion handler`? Is it in swift concepts? And what do you mean by `continue`. Is it `async` & `await`?

Comment: Watch "Meet async await" completion handlers are not used with the new "Concurrency"/`async await` framework, they are the "old way" of doing asynchronous work and must be converted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like since the last time I looked at the API Firebase has provided its own `async/await` methods. For uploading images it is `imageRef.putDataAsync(imageData)`.

```
///Uploads Data to the designated path in `FirebaseStorage`
static func upload(imageData: Data, path: String) async throws -> URL{
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let imageRef = storageRef.child(path)
    
    let metadata = try await imageRef.putDataAsync(imageData)
    return try await imageRef.downloadURL()
}
```

Then you can use `withThrowingTaskGroup` to upload simultaneously or use a regular `for` loop to upload 1x1.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorageSwift
import FirebaseStorage
struct ImageStorageService{
    static private let storage = Storage.storage()
    ///Uploads a multiple images as JPEGs and returns the URLs for the images
    ///Runs the uploads simultaneously
    static func uploadAsJPEG(images: [UIImage], path: String, compressionQuality: CGFloat = 1) async throws -> [URL]{
        return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: URL.self, body: { group in
            for image in images {
                group.addTask {
                    return try await uploadAsJPEG(image: image, path: path, compressionQuality: compressionQuality)
                }
            }
            var urls: [URL] = []
            for try await url in group{
                urls.append(url)
            }
            
            return urls
        })
    }
    
    ///Uploads a multiple images as JPEGs and returns the URLs for the images
    ///Runs the uploads one by one
    static func uploadAsJPEG1x1(images: [UIImage], path: String, compressionQuality: CGFloat = 1) async throws -> [URL]{
        var urls: [URL] = []
        for image in images {
            let url = try await uploadAsJPEG(image: image, path: path, compressionQuality: compressionQuality)
            urls.append(url)
        }
        return urls
    }
    ///Uploads a single image as a JPG and returns the URL for the image
    ///Runs the uploads simultaneously
    static func uploadAsJPEG(image: UIImage, path: String, compressionQuality: CGFloat = 1) async throws -> URL{
        guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: compressionQuality) else{
            throw ServiceError.unableToGetData
        }
        
        return try await upload(imageData: data, path: path)
    }
    ///Uploads Data to the designated path in `FirebaseStorage`
    static func upload(imageData: Data, path: String) async throws -> URL{
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let imageRef = storageRef.child(path)
        
        let metadata = try await imageRef.putDataAsync(imageData)
        return try await imageRef.downloadURL()
    }
    
    enum ServiceError: LocalizedError{
        case unableToGetData
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for good solution. I will try. I have a question. Should I hold `URL` type not `string`?  If so, why should I use `URL` type using Forestore? Does not matter using just `string`?

Comment: @Taro String is fine, you can map the array but since you get a url and you’ll need a url for async image why convert? But other than having to convert there is no other issue, you can create a function that takes in your upload type and returns an array of strings, then it can call the method you prefer like I do in the code.

Comment: I see. If I have a URL array when I use `async image`, don't need I to convert URL type, right? I have another question. If I use `URL` type for async image , I think Firestore doesn't support URL type. So when I upload image URL to Firestore, do I have to convert string?

Comment: Yes you can use it in async image, as far as Firestore it depends… if you are using DocumentID and firebase’s codable all the work will be done for you. Do you mind clicking on the check mark to accept this answer?

Comment: What do you mean by Firestore's data type? If imagesURL array is `URL` type, does it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72333366/async-await-function-not-not-loading-data/72333507#72333507

Comment: It will work URL is Codable. `struct ItemModel: Identifiable{
    @DocumentID var ref: DocumentReference?
    
    var id: String?{
        ref?.documentID
    }
    var imageURLs: [URL]
}` @Taro

Comment: Thank you. It did work!
I have another question. The above code is for the first time.
And I want to edit the previous post, I want to convert `URL` type to `UIImage`.
Because photo picker returns `UIImage`. Do you know a good solution?

Comment: You have to go in steps URL > Data > UIImage there are different ways of going from URL to UIImage just Google and search SO you’ll find at least a couple of different versions.