# swift - how to properly upload multiple images and await return values to then save in firebase db

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, firebase-storage

I am currently working on an app and I have been stuck on a problem involving completion handlers and async/await.

I am trying to upload multiple files to fire storage and return the file name and url in a simple custom struct:

```
struct PicData: Codable, Equatable {
    let id: String
    let link: URL
}
```

I use this function to upload a single image. I changed the completion return from "Void" to my struct, but both give me problems in my next function.

```
private func uploadPicture(picture: UIImage, completion: @escaping (PicData) -> PicData) async throws {
    guard let data = picture.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
        throw StorageError(message: "No data found in picture")
    }
    let fileName = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
    let picRef = storage.child("photos").child(someId).child(fileName)
    
    picRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error while uploading file: ", error)
            return
        }
        picRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if let theUrl = url {
                completion(PicData(id:fileName, link:theUrl))
            }
        })            
    }
}
```

I use the following function to upload multiple images. It's the main upload function Im calling from my View model -

```
 func uploadPictures(_ pics: [UIImage],  completion: @escaping ([PicData])->()) async throws {
        try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: PicData.self, body: { group in
            for (pic) in pics {
                group.addTask {
                    //let combo =
                    try await self.uploadPicture(picture: pic, completion: { (files)  in
                        return files
                    })
                    //return combo
                }
            }
            var fileNames: [PicData] = []
            for try await fileName in group{
                fileNames.append(PicData(id: fileName.id, link: fileName.link))
            }
            completion(fileNames)
        })
    }
```

And in my view model, I am trying to wait for the data before calling another function:

```
 func createNew(data: data, controller: UIViewController) async {
        self.isLoading = true
        Task{
            do {
               try await storageRepository.uploadPictures(data.pictures, completion: { pics in
                   Task {
                       do {
                           try await self.firestoreRepository.create(data: data, pictures: pics)
                           
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               self.isLoading = false // when this is published next view is shown.
                           }
                       }
                   }
                })
                
            } catch {
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

I've spent a lot of hours trying to search and figure things out, and I understand about async/await and completion handlers. I've rewritten my functions multiple times in different ways and the images are indeed successfully uploaded but my other functions don't wait. I understand the thread isn't waiting for a response, but having a hard time fixing it.

One of the main errors I keep running into other than it not waiting, is when I am trying to get the value from a function -

```
// from function: uploadPictures
    Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'PicData'
```

(That issue though is probably better off as it's own question)

I've also tried using Semaphores although my understanding is very limited --

```
 actor Datas {
        var combos: [PicData] = []
        func append(combo: PicData) {
            combos.append(combo)
        }
    }
    
func runSema(pics: [UIImage]) async -> [PicData] {
    let combo = Datas()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.myQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: pics.count)
    for pic in pics {
        queue.async {
            semaphore.wait()
            Task {
                do {
                    let com = try await self.uploadPicture(picture: pic)
                    print(com)
                    await combo.append(combo: com)
                } catch {
                    
                }
            }                
            semaphore.signal()
        }
    }
    return await combo.combos
}

private func uploadPicture(picture: UIImage) async throws -> PicData {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    guard let data = picture.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
        throw StorageError(message: "No data found in picture")
    }
    let fileName = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
    let picRef = storage.child("users").child(userId!).child(fileName)
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async {           
        semaphore.wait()
        picRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error while uploading file: ", error)
                //  return
            }
            picRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let theUrls = url else { return }
                semaphore.signal()
            }
        }            
    }
    let theUrl = try await picRef.downloadURL() // trying to get url outside of closure        
    return(PicData(id: fileName, link: theUrl))
}
```

and in my view model -

```
 func createNew(data: data, controller: UIViewController) {
        self.isLoading = true
        Task{
            do {
                let combos = await storageRepository.runSema(pics: profileData.pictures)
                
                try await self.firestoreRepository.create(data: data, pictures: combos)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isLoading = false // when this is published next view is shown.
                }
                
            } catch {
                publishError(message: error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

My files are uploaded but I can not get it to wait regardless what I've tried. I need to upload the files to storage then after, save my struct's data to Firestore DB.

I also tried to use putDataAsync with code I found on another SO answer, but kept getting this error -

> Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'putDataAsync'

```
func someUpload(someImagesData: [Data]) async throws -> [String]  {
    // your path
    let storageRef = storage.child("users").child(userId!).child("fileName")
    
    return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: String.self) { group in
        
        // the urlStrings you are eventually returning
        var urlStrings = [String]()
        
        // just using index for testing purposes so each image doesnt rewrites itself
        // of course you can also use a hash or a custom id instead of the index
        
        // looping over each image data and the index
        for (index, data) in someImagesData.enumerated() {
            
            // adding the method of storing our image and retriving the urlString to the task group
            group.addTask(priority: .background) {
                let _ = try await storageRef.putDataAsync(data)
                return try await storageRef.downloadURL().absoluteString
            }
        }
        
        for try await uploadedPhotoString in group {
            // for each task in the group, add the newly uploaded urlSting to our array...
            urlStrings.append(uploadedPhotoString)
        }
        // ... and lastly returning it
        return urlStrings
    }
}
```

At this point I give up, any ideas where I'm going wrong on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use async/await in for by Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573740/how-to-use-async-await-in-for-by-swift)

Comment: Don’t mix GCD and async await, it is a sure way to run into issues. Also you should not go from async await to completion handlers.

Comment: @loremipsum Ok thanks, I was trying alternative methods to see what works.  The linked SO question I am trying to see if that works but the first part of the answer keeps giving a similar error that's mentioned in my question `Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'putDataAsync`

Comment: Just update your Storage package/cocoa pod it is very new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @loremipsum's comments, it lead me in the right direction to get it figured out.

First I tried updating my packages via `File -> Packages -> Update..` and clean building, reset package cache, resolve versions, close Xcode, rebuild, etc. and nothing worked. What I had to do was remove the Firebase iOS SDK and then add a fresh install.

After doing so, a lot of errors popped up that originally wasn't there and didn't cause any problems before. Such as force unwrapping, and guard let statements, and I also had to add try await to some firebase calls. I was now able to use `putDataAsync`.

Using the link provide by @loremipsum I was able to modify my code and get it to work -

```
  ///Uploads Data to the designated path in `FirebaseStorage`
    func upload(picture: UIImage) async throws -> PicData {
        let fileName = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
        let imageRef = storage.child("someRef")
        guard let data = picture.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
            throw StorageError(message: "No data found in picture")
        }
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        let meta = try await imageRef.putDataAsync(data, metadata: metadata)
        let url = try await imageRef.downloadURL()
        return PicData(id: fileName, link: url)
    }

    ///Uploads a multiple images as JPEGs and returns the URLs for the images
    ///Runs the uploads simultaneously
    func uploadAsJPEG(pics: [UIImage]) async throws -> [PicData]{
        return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: PicData, body: { group in
            for pic in pics {
                group.addTask {
                    return try await self.upload(picture: pic)
                }
            }
            var urls: [PicData] = []
            for try await url in group{
                urls.append(url)
            }
            
            return urls
        })
    }
    
    
    func uploadAsJPEG1x1(images: [UIImage]) async throws -> [PicData]{
        var urls: [PicData] = []
        for image in images {
            let url = try await upload(picture: image)
            urls.append(url)
        }
        return urls
    }
```

And then in my view model I was able to call using try await and it actually waited this time.