# iOS - Uploading UIImage to Firebase Storage and Generating a URL - Error in For-In Loop?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-platform, swiftui, firebase-storage

So I am trying to use Firebase Storage to Upload Photos from an imagePicker in my viewModel. I'm appending my values to an array called images in my UI, which is an array of Image. I've verified that this indeed works and is populating the images array properly.

`@Published var images: [UIImage] = []`

```
func loadImages() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        images.append(inputImage)
        print("images array is currently \(images)")
}
```

However, when it comes to trying to upload to firebase, the UIImages are not being uploaded, and therefore, cannot generate a firebase URL for that. I believe it might be a problem with the way I'm looping through the UIImage array, because when I execute print statements, the index and the image is not being printed out, and therefore, I believe firebase is unable to add them to storage.

the relevant functions from my viewModel are:

```
func uploadAndUpdateImageURLs(email: String) {
        print("uploadAndUpdateImageURLs Reached")
        
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(email)")

        var imageURLs: [String] = []
        
        for (index, image) in images.enumerated() {
            print("index is of type \(type(of: index))")
            print("image is of type \(type(of: image))")
            print("index is currently: \(index)")
            print("image is currently: \(image)")
            let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
            let uniqueFileName = "\(timestamp)_\(email)_\(index).jpg"

            let imageRef = storageRef.child("\(email)/\(uniqueFileName)")
            let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)
            print("imageData is \(String(describing: imageData))")
            let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                guard let metadata = metadata else {
                    print("Uh-oh, an error occurred with the metadata!")
                    return
                }
                
                imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    guard let downloadURL = url else {
                        print("There was an error with the URL!")
                        return
                    }
                    print("The downloadURL will be \(downloadURL.absoluteString)")
                    imageURLs.append(downloadURL.absoluteString)
                    print("imageURLs is now: \(imageURLs)")
                }
            }
            
            uploadTask.resume()
            
            for imageURL in imageURLs {
                self.updateImageURLs(email: email, imageURL: imageURL)
            }
        }
    }


    
    func updateImageURLs(email: String, imageURL: String) {
        print("updateImageURLs function reached")
        db.collection("users").document(email).updateData(["imageURLs": FieldValue.arrayUnion([imageURL])]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error updating imageURLs: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Image URL Uploaded Successfully!")
            }
        }
    }
```

For a little more context, the UI where I'm getting the photos from is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImageView: View {
    var uiImage: UIImage
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }
}

struct ImageSelectorView: View {
    //@State private var images: [UIImage] = []
    //@State private var image: Image?
    //@State private var isShowingImagePicker = false
    //@State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = OnboardingViewModel()
    //@Binding var savedImages: [UIImage]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.secondary)
                    
                    Text("Tap To Select Photos")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.isShowingImagePicker = true
                }
                HStack {
                    ForEach(viewModel.images.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        ImageView(uiImage: viewModel.images[index])
                    }
                }
                

            }
            .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
            .onChange(of: viewModel.inputImage) { _ in
                viewModel.loadImages()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isShowingImagePicker) {
                ImagePicker(image: $viewModel.inputImage)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Am I correct in my suspicion to where the bug is occuring, and how would I fix it?

Comment: You are missing the asynchrone concept. If you look carefully, `print("updateImageURLs function reached")` is printed BEFORE `print("imageURLs is now: \(imageURLs)")` in Console while you expected the other way. Do the test with just one image to be easier to see. Look for "Swift + Closure + async" or "Swift async await"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573740/how-to-use-async-await-in-for-by-swift/75574381#75574381