# Download images in parallel with async/await in Swift

Tags: swift, async-await

For example, I get a list, which contains the image URL in each list item. I use the following approach to download images.

The limitation is image download is done one by one rather than in parallel. Is there any `async/await` related solution I can improve?

```swift
extension ImageDownloader {
    func fetchList() async -> [ListItem] {
        ...
    }
    
    func fetch(imageName: String) async -> Image {
        ...
    }
}


extension ImageDownloader {
    func download() async -> [Image] {
        var result = [Image]()
        let list = await fetchList()
        
        for item in list {
            print(item.imageName)
            let temp = await fetch(imageName: item.imageName) // Better way？
            result.append(temp)
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573740/how-to-use-async-await-in-for-by-swift/75574381#75574381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options to run these requests concurrently using a task group:

1. If you don't care about the order:

   ```swift
   func downloadInRandomOrder() async -> [Image] {
       await withTaskGroup(of: Image.self) { group in
           let items = await fetchList()

           for item in items {
               group.addTask { await self.fetch(imageName: item.imageName) }
           }

           return await group.reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1) }
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you want them returned in an order-independent structure (i.e., a `Dictionary`):

   ```swift
   func downloadInOrderIndependentDictionary() async -> [String: Image] {
       await withTaskGroup(of: (String, Image).self) { group in
           let items = await fetchList()

           for item in items {
               group.addTask { await (item.imageName, self.fetch(imageName: item.imageName)) }
           }

           return await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
       }
   }
   ```

   For what it’s worth, the first element of my tuple, which will become the key of the dictionary, is the `imageName`. But if `ListItem` was `Identifiable`, I’d be inclined to use the `id`, instead. Or however you uniquely identify `ListItem` instances. But without more information about `ListItem`, I had to guess. But hopefully you get the idea.
3. If you want them returned in order that `fetchList` returned them, you’d take that above `Dictionary` and build an `Array` from that:

   ```swift
   func downloadInOrder() async -> [Image] {
       await withTaskGroup(of: (String, Image).self) { group in
           let items = await fetchList()

           for item in items {
               group.addTask { await (item.imageName, self.fetch(imageName: item.imageName)) }
           }

           let dictionary = await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
           return items.compactMap { dictionary[$0.imageName] }
       }
   }
   ```

---

A few additional observations:

- It is interesting question as to whether you really want to return an array of `Image` and discard the underlying `ListItem` (which presumably has a interesting and related bunch of properties). You might consider returning both the `ListItem` and its associated `Image`.

  Alternatively, you might pull the `fetchList` out of this routine, and have the caller (a) fetch the list of images; and then (b) start fetching the images. That way, the view’s model knows how many images are being fetched, can show placeholders for images not yet fetched, etc.
- Note that this pattern of retrieving all the `Image` up-front is a bit of an antipattern. You generally want to fetch the images as needed. E.g., if there were 1000 `ListItem`, but you can only see 10 at any point in time, do you really want this to `await` the retrieval of all of the images? Do you really want to risk having images that are visible on screen to get backlogged by the retrieval of other images?

  Also, images can often take a lot of memory, so you might not want to retrieve more than you wanted. E.g., we’d often consider using [`AsyncImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage/) to achieve more of a just-in-time retrieval of these assets.

  But there is not enough here to get specific on the solution, as we’d need info about `ListItem`, whether it is `Identifiable` or not, whether there is utility in retrieving this information, too, etc. But I just wanted to acknowledge these additional considerations.
- You might also consider an `AsyncSequence`, namely an `AsyncStream`, to `yield` the images as they are retrieved. That way you can have the UI reflect the additional images as they come in rather than waiting for all of them at the end. That might look like:

  ```swift
  func images() async -> AsyncStream<(String, Image)> {
      AsyncStream { continuation in
          let task = Task {
              await withTaskGroup(of: (String, Image).self) { group in
                  let items = await fetchList()

                  for item in items {
                      group.addTask { await (item.imageName, self.fetch(imageName: item.imageName)) }
                  }

                  for await (name, image) in group {
                      continuation.yield((name, image))
                  }

                  continuation.finish()
              }
          }

          continuation.onTermination = { _ in
              task.cancel()                
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  And then the view might do something like:

  ```swift
  func startFetching() async {
      let sequence = await downloader.images()
      for await (name, image) in sequence {
          // update state/UI here
      }
  }
  ```

  If SwiftUI, you could just invoke this from the [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier. That will automatically cancel it when the view is dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the images in parallel, using `withTaskGroup`.

Example code:

```
extension ImageDownloader {
    
    func download() async -> [Image] {
        var result = [Image]()
        let list: [ListItem] = await fetchList()

        // --- get all images concurrently
        return await withTaskGroup(of: (Image.self)) { group -> Void in
            for item in list {
                if let url = URL(string: item.imageName) {
                    group.addTask { await fetch(imageName: item.imageName) }
                }
            }
            for await value in group {
                result.append(value)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

extension ImageDownloader {
    
    func fetchList() async -> [ListItem] {
       // ...
    }
    
    func fetch(imageName: String) async -> Image {
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: imageName)
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) { return Image(uiImage: img) }
        }
        catch { print(error) }
        return Image()
    }
}
```

Comment: When collecting the result, you are using a Task which executes explicitly on the main thread via `@MainThread`.  Is there any reason for this? IMHO, you should be able to avoid a context switch with `return await group.map {$0}.reduce(into:...)`.

Comment: MainActor does not make sense here you can bring the variable in the task group and return it. It is kind of anti pattern since async await is meant to be the ones that handles what actor to use.

Comment: yes, sorry, no need for the `Task{ @MainActor` I copied this from another part of my code, it should not be there. I'll update my answer.