SwiftUI .onAppear Does Not update @State variable with returned value
I'm trying to call a function I created which should fetch URLs from google cloud storage (firebase) when the view appears. I don't have any errors, but the code doesn't display any of my images. Have I missed a step in the construction of my code? By the way the code shown below is self-contained inside of the view. I plan on seperating things once I figure out what's going on.
Here's the code I have so far:
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseStorage



func testingCall(){
    let _ = print("Test")
}


struct GalleryView: View {
    @State var photos = [String]()
    
    func getDownloadURl() -> [String] {
            var photoURLS = [String]()
            let ref = Storage.storage().reference()
            
            let storageReference = ref.child("images/")
            storageReference.listAll { (result, error) in
              if let error = error {
                print(error)
              }
                for item in result!.items {
                //List storage reference
                let storageLocation = String(describing: item)
                let gsReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: storageLocation)
                
                // Fetch the download URL
                gsReference.downloadURL { url, error in
                  if let error = error {
                    // Handle any errors
                    print(error)
                  } else {
                    // Get the download URL for each item storage location
                    print(url!)
                    print(type(of: url!))
                    print(type(of: url!.absoluteString))
                      photoURLS.append(url!.absoluteString)
                      print(photoURLS)
                  }
                }
                
                
              }
            }
            return photoURLS
        }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [
                    GridItem(.fixed(100)),
                    GridItem(.fixed(100)),
                    GridItem(.fixed(100))
                ], spacing: 12, content:{
                    ForEach(photos, id: \.self){ photoURL in
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string:photoURL)){ result in
                                if let result = result.image{
                                    result
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width:124,height:124)
                                }
                                
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.red)
                        
                    }
                })
            }.navigationTitle("Gallery")
                .onAppear{
                    photos = self.getDownloadURl()
                }
        }
    }
}

Thank you in advance for any tips. I greatly appreciate it.

You need to updates the view as part of the completion handler, which is asynchronous, not as part of the synchronous method which will complete and return (an empty array) before any values are generated from the completion handler.

Google "Firebase Swift Async" to start getting some ideas of how to deal with these async functions. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573740/how-to-use-async-await-in-for-by-swift

Thanks for the comment and the nudge in the a better direction. I'm fairly new to SwiftUI/Swift. Would you happen to know which Apple docs I should look at to understand how to use this suggestion?

@jnpdx Ah Thanks! I was just asking for this exactly.

try .task instead of .Appear but you'll need to change the func to be async and wrap your callback in a continuation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation

Array is a struct, so it is a value type.  That means "photoURLs" won't be the same object as "photos".  So anything you do on photoURLs won't affect photos except on your onAppear, and all your completion codes will be called after onAppear.
Try to append urls to photos instead of photoURLs

This is pretty much the route I took and I also added DispatchQueue.main.async to my .onAppear which worked. Now on to a different issue with loading images once tapped (and displaying the correct one) Fun times!
